# How to do binary search in java?

Tags: java, binary-search

Im working on a project in which it reads book titles in from a .txt file and puts them into an arraylist, then the arraylist is converted to an array, The user enters a number which is the books reference number, then it does a linear search and a binary search to find that book. Im just having a trouble with the code for the binary search, as far as my knowledge of binary searching goes, this is what I have put together, so what is wrong with my binary search code?

```
 int left = 0,right = bookList.length;
int int1;
int1 = Integer.parseInt(input);
while(left <= right){
    int middle = (right + left)/2;
    int compare = input.compareTo(bookList[middle].referenceNumber);
    if(compare == 0){
        Output2.setText("The book is " + bookList[middle].title);
    } else if(compare < int1){
        right = middle - 1;
        left = 0;
        if(compare == 0){
          Output2.setText("The book is " + bookList[middle].title);
        }
    } else if(compare > int1){
        right = bookList.length;
        left = middle + 1;
        if(compare == 0){
            Output2.setText("The book is " + bookList[middle].title);
        }
    }
    }
```

Below is my the book class and booklist array

```
public class Book{
String referenceNumber, title;

public Book(String _referenceNumber, String _title){
   referenceNumber = _referenceNumber;
   title = _title;
}
}

 ArrayList <Book> Books = new ArrayList <Book> ();
 Book [] bookList;
```

Thanks for any help you might be able to offer

Comment: Please don't repost essentially the same question twice.  Also, before posting you should be using a debugger to trace through the code to determine where the problem is.  Debugging and tracing are a crucial parts of the learning process and if you just ask here and get an answer you won't have learned much.

Answer (score 0):

Don't set left to zero or right to .length when you reduce your range. You have to keep the old values.

```
int left = 0,right = bookList.length;
int int1;
int1 = Integer.parseInt(input);
while(left <= right){
    int middle = (right + left)/2;
    int compare = input.compareTo(bookList[middle].referenceNumber);
    if(compare == 0){
        Output2.setText("The book is " + bookList[middle].title);
    } else if(compare < int1){
        right = middle - 1;
        if(compare == 0){
          Output2.setText("The book is " + bookList[middle].title);
        }
    } else if(compare > int1){
        left = middle + 1;
        if(compare == 0){
            Output2.setText("The book is " + bookList[middle].title);
        }
    }
    }
```